# Mysql connection doesn't work with "using"

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying this

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY name";

using(MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(conn))
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConn);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But it returns an error on MysqlCommand line, saying Connection must be valid and open. Anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error message is so clear IMO..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't open the connection in your code, You should call

`dbConn.Open();`

It has nothing to do with `using` statement.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY name";
using(MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(conn))
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConn);
    dbConn.Open();//here **
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

`using` statement only ensures that the your connection object will be disposed after the scope, it doesn't open the connection itself.

Comment: You should wrap the command object in a `using` too, Habib.  +1 regardless.